# How routing is done in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter-2

I could not find the `.htaccess` file in `CodeIgniter` framework and i'm wondering how do they do route without it? Or it is somewhere hidden?

Comment: @Mischa no, i want to know how they did it.

Comment: Everything goes to index.php that then sends all data to the framework. That said to work with nice URLs you'll nedd a minimal htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no .htaccess by default provided with codeigniter. They serve it through the index.php. .htaccess is only used to direct the urls to the index.php. This way codeigniter is working in environments where rewriting isn't allowed. Another way of getting controller and function is by query strings. 
Anyway the actual routing is done in system/core/Router.php so you can read the code. Since Codeigniter is open source application that can't be hidden.